# Electronjs app icons are big when launching in wsl2 using Xlaunch?

Tags: electron, fish, wsl-2, xserver, xlaunch

I have enabled WSL 2. I have also installed VcXsrv (I think its also called Xlaunch?).

I opened the settings and overrode these properties for XLaunch.exe as shown below:

[image]

After that I clicked XLaunch.exe and added `-ac` in one of the boxes as shown below and then pressed OK. This launched an instance of XLaunch/VcXsrv in my system tray.

[image]

Now I opened my terminal (in WSL 2) and `git clone`d the demo Electron app from their [website](https://www.electronjs.org/). After running `npm install` and `npm start`, I see a window, but the icons are large.

I also tried adding these environment variables to my shell rc (I am using fish shell).

```
set -x DISPLAY {mywslip}:0
set -x LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT 1
set -x GDK_SCALE 2
set -x GDK_DPI_SCALE 0.5
```

But even after this, Electron app's icons and text is a little bit large. To confirm if this was an Electron issue, I did `npm start` in my host machine (i.e., using Windows `cmd` meaning I ran it not in WSL 2, but on host windows machine itself). However in this case, it works perfectly fine, icons are perfectly scaled.

I think I need to play around with these environment variables, but is there an automatic fix without my having to guess the numbers for `GDK_SCALE` etc?

Note: I have a normal 1920 x 1080p resolution laptop with me.

Comment: So you have "a normal [...] laptop" screen -- you're not trying to get this app working on a High-DPI display, right? If your display is not High-DPI, then why do you want to configure X11 to upscale small things? These settings are (AFAIK) meant to help people having difficulties reading small text on such high-resolution monitors by scaling everything up by a specified factor (in fact, GTK applications use `GDK_SCALE`, I guess). Take a look at the [GTK+ documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-x11.html), you shouldn't have to set these values.

Comment: I am not sure how to calculate DPI, but I have a normal 15.6 inch laptop with 1920x1080p resolution. I want to launch electron apps through WSL2. And from online docs and tutorials, apparently I needed some x window server(xlaunch is one of them?). However, the same electron app is scaled differently when run on WSL2 vs when run from host windows machine. I am just trying to sync these up.

Comment: At this point, I believe that the app is scaled differently when run from WSL 2 because you told X11 (VcXsrv) to enable High-DPI upscaling (basically: "Hey, please **enlarge** everything by a certain factor!"), which it gladly does. As I said, you probably have a normal display and it thus makes no sense to activate scaling (what you've done in your first step) and setting these environment variables. Try to revert these changes and take a look if the application is still too large. I'd be surprised if it was. If this actually is the issue, I'll gladly prepare an answer with more details.